# How do I prevent the contents of .join() from being added after the last value of my array?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var e = 0;
var f = 0;
var alphaA = $("#inOne").val();
var alphaB = $("#inTwo").val();
var betaA = parseFloat(alphaA);
var betaB = parseFloat(alphaB);
var numa = Math.abs(betaA);
var numb = Math.abs(betaB);
var factorA = [];
var factorB = [];
var commonFactor = [];

for (d = 0; d <= b; d++){
   for (e = 0; e <= c; e++){
      if (factorA[d] == factorB[e]) {
         commonFactor[f] = factorA[d];
            f++;
       }
    }
}
f--;
document.getElementById("cF").innerHTML = "Common Factors: " + commonFactor.join(", ");
```

If the values of my array are [1, 2, 4], the output is 
**Common Factors: 1, 2, 4,**
How do I stop the ", " from appearing after the 4 How do I make it look like: **1, 2, 4**

Comment: `[1, 2, 4].join(', ')` is `1, 2, 4` for me

Comment: `join` doesn't add anything else. You might have an `undefined` value in there EDIT: [1, 2, 4, undefined].join(', ') === [1,2,3,4,]

Comment: looks like somewhere in your factorA and factorB presents undefined or null. Look:
`[1,undefined,null,2].join(",")` produces `1,,,2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[1, 2, 4, undefined, null].filter(e=>!!e).join(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

join() does not insert anything after the last character. Here is an example of separating each character in a string with underscore ("_"). It adds underscore after every character, but not after last character.

```js
var str = "this is to explain join";
document.getElementById("output").textContent = str.split('').join('_');
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: So then why does it do that? Is it possible that there is another value which is undefined?